# why this message come in php:notice undefined offset:2

Tags: php

I want to use the project PHP Weather 2.2.2 but it has many problems
here is a code

```
function get_languages($type) {

    static $output = array();

    if (empty($output)) {

        /* I use dirname(__FILE__) here instead of PHPWEATHER_BASE_DIR
         * because one might use this function without having included
         * phpweather.php first. */
        require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/languages.php');

        $dir = opendir(dirname(__FILE__) . '/output');
        while($file = readdir($dir)) {

            // I got a problem in  this line below     

            if (ereg("^pw_${type}_([a-z][a-z])(_[A-Z][A-Z])?\.php$", $file, $regs)) {

            // After i change it to the line mentioned below i got error undefined offset:2 in line 2 mentioned below
            // how to correct this error or is there any way to correct this code

            if(preg_match("#^pw_${type}_([a-z][a-z])(_[A-Z][A-Z])?\.php$#", $file, $regs)) {
                $output[$regs[1] . $regs[2]] = $languages[$regs[1] . $regs[2]];
            }
        }
        closedir($dir);
    }

    asort($output);

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: are you sure $regs[2] is existing?

Comment: `var_dump($regs);` you will get your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You see this notice because the `$regs[2]` is not set.

```
if(preg_match("#^pw_${type}_([a-z][a-z])(_[A-Z][A-Z])?\.php$#", $file, $regs)) {
    $output[$regs[1] . (isset($regs[2]) ? $regs[2] : '')] = $languages[$regs[1] . (isset($regs[2]) ? $regs[2] : '')];
}
```

use `isset()` for checking is exists an array value or no. If no exists concatenation with empty string `''`

That is because you use **?** in your regex `(_[A-Z][A-Z])?`

Comment: thanks.. error is remove now

Answer (score 0):

Use this regular expression:

```
        if(preg_match("#^pw_${type}_([a-z][a-z])((?:_[A-Z][A-Z])?)\.php$#", $file, $regs)) {
```

The group with `?:` will not be a capture group, it exists just to allow you to apply the `?` modifier to it. Wrapping it in another group captures the contents of that; if the optional regexp wasn't matched, this will be an empty string.